# Identifier is undefined (in C)

Tags: c

This is the code I am trying to write:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
    printf("Type coordinates of the first point: ");
    scanf_s("%i%i", &x1, &y1);
    printf("Type coordinates of the second point: ");
    scanf_s("%i%i", &x2, &y2);
    printf("Type coordinates of the third point: ");
    scanf_s("%i%i", &x3, &y3);
    printf("This is the area: %i",
        0.5 * ((x1 * (y2−y3)+x2 * (y3−y1)+x3 * (y1−y2))); //here i get the error
    return 0;
}
```

and I get the error at `(y2-y3)` and `(y1-y2)` for Identifier is undefined. Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the exact error message. Copy&paste directly into the question.

Comment: Your spacing is strange: `(y2−y3)+x2 * (...` Why do you add spaces around `*` but no spaces around `+`? You know that normal mathematical rules apply, right?

Comment: If the dash character you show in the question is actually in your source file rather than a hyphen (“-”), then you may need to stop using a word-processing application to edit your source files and use an application intended for programming source code or for plain text files. Failing that, you need to turn off features in your word-processing application that convert hyphens to dashes, as well as turning off other conversions like plain quotes to open quotes and close quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the last `printf`. it seems you are using an incorrect decrement operator `-`.

fix it like that:

```
    printf("This is the area: %lf",
            0.5 * ((x1 * (y2-y3)+x2 * (y3-y1)+x3 * (y1-y2))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `-` instead of `−`

Comment: Without an explanation of the difference, this distinction isn’t obvious, and for the same reason that the author likely missed this issue in the first place.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
    printf("Type coordinates of the first point: ");
    scanf("%i%i", &x1, &y1);
    printf("Type coordinates of the second point: ");
    scanf("%i%i", &x2, &y2);
    printf("Type coordinates of the third point: ");
    scanf("%i%i", &x3, &y3);
    printf("This is the area: %lf",
        0.5 * (x1 * (y2-y3)+x2 * (y3-y1)+x3 * (y1-y2)));
         //here i get the error
   
      return 0;
}
```

1. Your `scanf_s` doesn't provide the length argument, so some other number is used. It isn't determinate what value it finds, so you get eccentric behaviour from the code. so use `scanf()` instead of `scanf_s()`
2. you used an extra `(` on your last `printf` statement.
3. you used the wrong type of decrement operator between `(y2-y3)`,`(y3-y1)` and `(y1-y2)`
4. and use `%lf` instead of `%i` because your last printf takes the argument of type `double`